How to access the wwwroot of a Blazor application running on Linux with Nginx and Kestrel?
I'm a beginner in using Blazor, and for study purposes, I decided to set up a small server Raspberry Pi with Raspberry Pi OS Lite 64 Bits, .Net Core 8.0, Nginx, and Kestrel.
I successfully deployed a BlazorWebApp frontend that communicates with a Web API. Except for the following: I can't access the folders in wwwroot so my page doesn't load images or JavaScript.
I've been on this issue for a few weeks and I'm going crazy. I've tried all kinds of configurations in Nginx, Kestrel, and program.cs.
The commands that are usually needed in Program.cs seem to have no effect at all.
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();

app.UseStaticFiles();

I tried these and various variations of them.
Am I missing something because it's a Raspberry Pi or because it's not Ubuntu? Maybe I should leave Nginx behind and try Apache?
I'm really going in circles here. I appreciate any advice.
As I said, I tried multiple configurations in the three key points: Program.cs, Nginx, and Kestrel. I also changed the permissions of wwwroot and the owner: root, www-data, but nothing works. The application log "NLog" doesn't tell me anything. And despite having active logs, the Nginx logs are always empty (could this be part of the problem?).
I searched the internet, but I couldn't find anything related to deployment on Raspberry Pi.
Sorry, I'll try to provide more data and be more direct and technical in the text.
Browser debug
As you can see in the image, I'm getting a 404 error for a file that is in wwwroot/javascript, yet aap.css that is in wwwroot loads normally. I've already tried placing the files in wwwroot without subfolders, without success.
Here's a snippet from my default Nginx file, root was one of the last attempts to make wwwroot accessible:
 #rasp Bank Statement (Frontend)
    location /bank/ {
        root /var/www/app/BlazorBankStatement/wwwroot;
        proxy_pass         http://192.168.0.156:5023;
        include            proxy_params;
        access_log         /var/log/nginx/srv.local-bank-access.log;
        error_log          /var/log/nginx/srv.local-bank-error.log;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For 
        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
        proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128; 
    }

Here the kestrel Service file:
[Unit]
Description= FrontEnd BankStatement
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/app/BlazorBankStatement/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dotnet /var/www/app/BlazorBankStatement/BlazorFront.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=YourApp
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://192.168.0.156:5023

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

And finally the program.cs code, it may be a little messed up due to my several attempts to access wwwroot:
using BlazorFront.Components;
using BlazorFront.Service;
using BlazorFront.Service.Interface;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Adding Nlog to the pipeline
builder.Logging.AddNLog();

// Configure Kestrel to listen on all network interfaces on port 5023

// Adds the UseStaticWebAssets middleware to serve static files, including CSS, in production
if (!builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.Listen(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.156"), 5023);
        
    });
    
    builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
    //builder.Services.AddDirectoryBrowser();
}

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
                .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

// WEB API ADDRESS (change according to your deployment)
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp =>
    new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.0.156:5020")
    });

//Download Service
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFileDownloadService, FileDownloadService>();

var app = builder.Build();


app.UseStaticFiles();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

//Configuration of forwarded header to work with reverse proxy... Ngnix
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

//REMOVED TO AVOID AUTHENTICATION ERROR IN Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider ON Raspbery PI
//app.UseAuthentication();

//app.UseFileServer();
//var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
//provider.Mappings["{EXTENSION}"] = "{CONTENT TYPE}";
//app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { ContentTypeProvider = provider });
//app.UseFileServer(enableDirectoryBrowsing: true);



app.Run();

Project & Type

Debugging details would include what's shown in the Network tab in the Browser. Also post your <base href= /> line. Check it against your App URLs.

I had a coworker setup a Raspberry and know a little about what he did.  The raspberry has two drives mounted.  One is a Linux Drive and one is a Windows Drive. You can use the Linux command Mount to see the drivers.  Ubuntu is a different version of Linux than  the Raspberry version.  I think your issue is using the Windows mounted drive instead of the Linux mounted drive.  Not an Ubuntu issue.

I created a Blazor application in VS2022 using the new Blazor Web App template. The only reference of  is in App.razor in the components folder, actually using the directive: app.UseStaticFiles();. Blazor should be able to interact with a file like wwwroot/javascript/script.js with a path like /javascript/script.js, which is exactly how it is. The paths are correct, I believe the wwwroot folder should appear for me in debug in the browser, but it doesn't.

@Lauris - we still dn't know if you get 404 or 403 or ...

I added more information about the code and the 404 error in the question.

The index.html might help, given that app.css does load.

Actually, I saw some mentions about the index.html and index.cshtml files, but my project doesn't have these types of files. (I added a new image with the project folders open and the type of template I chose to make this frontend) The fact that app.css is loading is a mystery. Should I have an index file in my project? The only page of this small project is Home.Razor.

No, in this case it's App.razor in the server project. Where base href is, and the css files are linked in.

Yes. I tried to load the files through App.razor and also change  to , but that messes everything up. I still think it's something in Nginx. My project is very peculiar because it's running on a Raspberry Pi. I'm running out of ideas. I was hoping someone had already made a similar arrangement.

I finally found my mistake. I published the solution.

Well. I feel kind of stupid after almost dismantling my server to solve this problem, but I finally found the problem and its solution.
The problem:
The original file is "javascript/downloadService.js", but when you drag it through Visual Studio 2022 to take advantage of the automatic path inclusion, VS transforms it from "javascript/downloadService.js" to "javascript/downloadservice.js", putting everything in lowercase!
So here's a tip, folks: Be careful when dragging the file through the IDE and always. Always check the file name. Anyway, the code I posted in the question is correct, and I hope it can help someone in the future.
